# Set rows to repeat at top when printing - PHPExcel

Tags: phpexcel

I need to put table head row to each printed page while printing a long data sheet([like this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repeat-specific-rows-or-columns-on-every-printed-page-0d6dac43-7ee7-4f34-8b08-ffcc8b022409)), but I failed to find any related setup in PHPExcel, could anyone faced the same problem help me out?

Comment: Please provide your requirements as completely as possible inside the question itself.  Linking to another site makes it difficult to quickly answer you.   Also, you need to make sure to include everything you've tried, and what the output actually was vs what you expected.

Answer (score 9):

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setRowsToRepeatAtTopByStartAndEnd(1,1);
```

This worked for me

Comment: Not clear for me but I figured out that you have to put what rows you want to repeat. In his example, the first row is repeating on print on each page. If you need the 6 and 7 rows just put (6,7) or (6,6) to repeat only the 6th row.

Comment: Yes, it is working for me. But if we want that the header or title should be on specific pages like the first three pages at that time what should we do, there is not any way to just define it for specific pages.